# Сохранить изменения в .xml -файле, помещенном в .zip

Tags: c#

Если .xml не в архиве, с сохранением проблем не возникает. В архиве же никак не получается сохранить. Как это можно сделать?
В классе XmlDocument четыре метода Save(). Но, честно признаться, не получается ни с одним из них.

```
using System.Xml;
using System.IO.Compression;

string zipPath = @"D:\\z1.zip";
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
       ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.GetEntry("xml1.xml");
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

       doc.Load(entry.Open());
       XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("descendant::People");
       string str = node.InnerText;

       node.InnerText = "12345";
       doc.Save(...);
}
```

Comment: Сохранять тоже нужно с помощью ZipFile.

Comment: А как это сделать? .rtf с содержимым RichTextBox сохраняется обыкновенно с помощью Save(). Только с xml так не получается. И в классе ZipFile я не нашел методов сохранения.

Comment: Если ответ вас устраивает отметьте его галочкой.

Comment: Это мне?) Я давно отметил)

Comment: Вероятно вы проголосовали за ответ, но не отметили его как лучший ([галочка под стрелками голосований](https://image.prntscr.com/image/dA2L8ZGKQTetjCRP370_rg.png)).

Comment: Не знал, спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string path = @"D:\z1.zip";
using (var zipToOpen = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) 
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipToOpen, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    var zipArchiveEntry = archive.GetEntry("xml1.xml");
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    using (var stream = zipArchiveEntry.Open())
    {
        doc.Load(stream);
        var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("descendant::People");
        node.InnerText = "12345";
        stream.SetLength(0); //Устанавливаем длину потока в 0 на случай, если новое содержимое файла короче предыдущего. Например был удален узел.
        doc.Save(stream);
    }
}
```